# native-activity sample project won't compile if I change file exteension to .cpp

Tags: c++, android-ndk

I've compiled the native activity sample and it runs fine. When I switch from main.c to main.cpp I get a compiler error

```
$ /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r7/ndk-build
make: *** No rule to make target `jni/main.c', needed by `obj/local/armeabi/objs/native-activity/main.o'.  Stop.
```

I changed the make file to main.cpp.

I'm new to Android and Linux. I'm using Cygwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to delete the object files. Dumb mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Android.mk file looking for `main.c` and change it to main.cpp

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.c
```

must be:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
```

Comment: I did that. That's what I meant by changing the make file. I should have been more clear.